# regular expressions for finding multi lines

Tags: regex, ruby

Full text:

```rb
def A
    pod 'Xyz', '0.1.0'
    pod 'zdb', '1.1.0+beta'
    pod 'Aero', '3.1.0'
end

def B
    A
    pod 'qq', '0.1.1'
    pod 'publ', '1.1.0'
end
```

I want a function, the input value would be 'A' or 'B', the return value would be the multi lines.
The pod name's character may be anything.

For example, If I input 'A', the result would be

```rb
pod 'Xyz', '0.1.0'
pod 'zdb', '1.1.0+beta'
pod 'Aero', '3.1.0'
```

If I input 'B', the result would be

```rb
pod 'Xyz', '0.1.0'
pod 'zdb', '1.1.0+beta'
pod 'Aero', '3.1.0'
pod 'qq', '0.1.1'
pod 'publ', '1.1.0'
```

How can I match this text?

Comment: What are you actually trying to *achieve*? My guess is that possibly you're trying to define multiple targets in a `Podfile`, with minimal repetition?

Comment: I ask this, because it feels like a potential XY problem to me: You're asking for help with a proposed solution, without stating the original underlying problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done using regex. *I have not used ruby before so I will **not** be able to share any code*. I did check few posts online to help me writing an answer.

---

### Regex

```
"(?<=def [A-#{input}]\n)[^p]*(pod '.*?')(?=\nend)"gs
```

here `#{input}` is your *input variable*. *Please note that the regex must be applied **globally** and in **single line mode** (dot matches new line character)*. You have to do that in ruby. As I already mentioned, I can not do it.

---

### Output

I tried manually changing the input and testing it against your input string.

```
input 1:
A

match 1-group 1:
pod 'Xyz', '0.1.0'
    pod 'zdb', '1.1.0+beta'
    pod 'Aero', '3.1.0'


input 2:
B

match 1-group 1:
pod 'A-a', '0.1.0'
    pod 'A-b', '1.1.0'
    pod 'A-c', '3.1.0'

match 2-group 1:
pod 'B-a', '0.1.1'
    pod 'B-b', '1.1.0'
```

---

As you can see, *if applied globally*, all the lines you are interested in will be obtained in ***group 1** will some additional spaces* which can always be eliminated.

Test link: https://regex101.com/r/AljaZP/1

Comment: Your answer is well, but the pod name may be something like 'xyz123' and not just 'A-a'. Sorry for my example not illustrate it.

Comment: Could you edit the answer to specify the format of pod name? If the pod name will not contain A, B and so on *( which is something where we anchor our match on)*  then the above regex will not work.

Comment: @jseanj I have edited my answer. It's not perfect but it does capture what you want.